# Better way of clearing an input buffer?

Tags: c++, buffer, numeric-limits

I am learning how to clear an input buffer. So far I have come across two statements that both work and seem to do the same thing:

```
while(getchar() != '\n');
```

```
cin.ignore(numberic_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Is there any difference for choosing one over the other, besides the fact that the second is more typing and requires that you include an additional header file?

Here is the first program I ran. At the first prompt, I entered `"Sandy askdjfhlaf"`. At the second prompt, I entered `"Cheeks"`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    
    string first_name;
    string last_name;
    
    cout << "First name: ";
    cin >> first_name;
        
    while(getchar() != '\n'); // the statement in question    
    
    cout << "Last name: ";
    cin >> last_name;
    
    cout << first_name << ' ' << last_name;
    
    return 0;
}
```

The output was:

```
Sandy Cheeks
```

Here is the second program I ran. I tested this second program with the same input:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    
    string first_name;
    string last_name;
    
    cout << "First name: ";
    cin >> first_name;
    
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // the statement in question    
    
    cout << "Last name: ";
    cin >> last_name;
    
    cout << first_name << ' ' << last_name;
    
    return 0;
}
```

I expected the program to either behave differently than the first program, or to produce different output. However, the result appeared to be identical.

Comment: The first will have an infinite loop if end of file is reached before a newline is encountered.

Comment: Note that in the 2nd case, you don't HAVE to use `numeric_limits`, you can use any integer that is sufficiently larger than the max console input. It is just that `ignore()` is specifically designed to read infinitely when passed `numeric_limits::max()`, so that you don't have to guess at what size to use

Comment: @RemyLebeau  As you say, the standard specifies what happens when `std::ignore()` is given a value `numeric_limits<streamsize>::max()`.    But writing a program that *assumes* a maximum input size (or what is "sufficiently larger") can be problematical when reading user input, since users are notorious for not complying with assumptions (say, on how much or what they type) made by programmers.

Comment: @Peter I was thinking of in-data, but I now realize you've dealt with it already. Sorry.